Does the FBI tell you if they take on a case you asked them to look into?
I'm dealing with a dirty courthouse that has chosen to take the path of inaction for a civil rights violation, and was wondering what the FBI (US Marshals said they investigate dirty courthouses when a state refuses to hold parties accountable) normally does if they decide to take on a case you contacted them about. There's a precident in Ohio where a father who was an officer who was fired over trying the same thing with her daughters boyfriend.
When complaining to local law enforcment they have huge smiles on their faces, and seem extremely nice, but I'm not going away in 6+ years asking for equal access to justice when they caused a continuous harm. One officer was very accusational until I put him in my shoes by asking what he would choose for his spouse (either what I chose, or he's a danger to his wife).

The general rule for law enforcement is that information comes into an investigation, it doesn't go out. The only time law enforcement will say anything to outsiders is when they think it will move the investigation forwards (e.g. appeal for information) or in high profile matters when there is a lot of press interest. And even then they will say as little as possible.

If they decide to act on it, there's a decent chance they'll need to contact you for additional information. If you never hear from their investigators, you can probably guess it's not a high priority.

It is very likely that the investigators have determined that there was no crime committed that can be proved beyond a reasonable doubt. If the matter is six years or more old, the statute of limitations for both criminal and civil matters has also probably expired. An officer being fired is not a legal precedent. People can be fired for all sorts of things that aren't crimes and don't create civil liability enforceable with a lawsuit. Most courthouse violations of civil rights involve absolute or qualified immunity from civil liability and sometimes immunity from criminal liability. Give up.

FBI takes over investigations when locals can't/won't do their jobs. This is when the concept of neglegence takes over. I think what you're now saying is that when you say there's no just cause for a conviction, and you put that as the reason on an application it turns into the background check being held accountable if they refuse to verify the cause.

No
They can if they want to but no law requires them to.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
